# How do i cue multiple videos in a list or array view using Youtube's api?

Tags: android, api, listview, youtube

i have been experimenting with the youtube api and have settled on using the simle player view as it is most efficient for what i want. However i wish to have multiple videos cued in a list so that the user can click on whichever one they want after scrolling

code

```
public class PlayerViewDemoActivity extends YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.playerview_demo);

YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
youTubeView.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
  boolean wasRestored) {
if (!wasRestored) {
  player.cueVideo("wKJ9KzGQq0w");
}
}

@Override
protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
}

}
```